# Is there a way to change the color of an icon by clicking on a list-item in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am creating a Dropdown-Menu in VueJS, I want to show an icon and by clicking on this icon a Dropdown-Menu with 3 other icons opens. By clicking on one of these icons, I want the Dropdown-Menu-Icon to change. I have already achieved all this, the only thing that doesn't seem to work is that I can't dynamically change the color of the icon (one icon is green, one is grey and one is red). 
I think that's because Vue doesn't let me set the color to a variable.

This is my Code for the menu:

```
    <v-card outlined>
        <v-card-title>Selection</v-card-title>

        <v-toolbar height="80" elevation="0">
            <v-menu
                    transition="slide-y-transition"
                    nudge-left="9"
                    nudge-bottom="10"
                    offset-y>

                <template v-slot:activator="{ on: menu }">
                    <v-tooltip right>
                        <template v-slot:activator="{ on:tooltip }">
                            <v-btn class="mb-6" v-on="{...tooltip, ...menu}" fab>
                                <v-icon x-large>{{ myIcon }}</v-icon>
                            </v-btn>
                        </template>
                        <span>Steady</span>
                    </v-tooltip>
                </template>


                <v-list>
                    <v-list-item>
                        <v-icon color="green" x-large @click="changeSupplierStatusToUp()">mdi-chevron-up</v-icon>
                    </v-list-item>

                    <v-divider></v-divider>


                    <v-list-item>
                        <v-icon color="grey" x-large @click="changeSupplierStatusToMid()">mdi-unfold-less-vertical
                        </v-icon>
                    </v-list-item>
                    <v-divider></v-divider>
                    <v-list-item>
                        <v-icon color="red" x-large @click="changeSupplierStatusToDown()">mdi-chevron-down</v-icon>
                    </v-list-item>
                </v-list>
            </v-menu>

        </v-toolbar>

    </v-card>
</template>
```

And this is my Javascript code:

```
<script>

    export default {
        name: "Selection",
        data() {
            return {
                myIcon: 'mdi-unfold-less-vertical',

        },
        props: {},
        computed: {

        },
        methods: {

            changeSupplierStatusToUp() {
                this.myIcon = 'mdi-chevron-up'

            },
            changeSupplierStatusToDown() {
                this.myIcon = 'mdi-chevron-down'

            },
            changeSupplierStatusToMid() {
                this.myIcon = 'mdi-unfold-less-vertical'

            }
    };
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Any help is appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the icon color to a variable and change that variable to the expected color in each of your functions.

The way I did this was to convert `myIcon` to an Object with properties for `name, color`.

I stored the colors as an Object for easy selection.

Then I attached the color of each `v-icon` to use the appropriate `colors` Object property.

In the click event for each icon, I change the `myIcon.name` and `myIcon.color`.

i.e.

```js
changeSupplierStatusToUp() {
  this.myIcon.name = 'mdi-chevron-up';
  this.myIcon.color = this.colors.green;
}
```

Ensure you preface the `color` prop with a colon (`:`) to make it reactive and to use a variable instead of text -- `<v-icon :color="colors.green" ...>`.

Then in your activator icon, `<v-icon x-large :color="myIcon.color">{{ myIcon.name }}</v-icon>`.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  name: "Selection",
  data() {
    return {      
      myIcon: {
        name: 'mdi-unfold-less-vertical',
        color: 'default'
      },
      colors: {
        green: 'green',
        grey: 'grey',
        red: 'red'
      }
    }
  },
  props: {},
  computed: {
    
  },
  methods: {
    changeSupplierStatusToUp() {
      this.myIcon.name = 'mdi-chevron-up';
      this.myIcon.color = this.colors.green;
    },
    changeSupplierStatusToDown() {
      this.myIcon.name = 'mdi-chevron-down';
      this.myIcon.color = this.colors.red;
    },
    changeSupplierStatusToMid() {
      this.myIcon.name = 'mdi-unfold-less-vertical';
      this.myIcon.color = this.colors.grey;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>



<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-card outlined>
      <v-card-title>Selection</v-card-title>
        <v-toolbar height="80" elevation="0">
          <v-menu
            transition="slide-y-transition"
            nudge-left="9"
            nudge-bottom="10"
            offset-y
          >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on: menu }">
              <v-tooltip right>
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on:tooltip }">
                  <v-btn class="mb-6" v-on="{...tooltip, ...menu}" fab>
                    <v-icon
                      x-large
                      :color="myIcon.color"
                    >{{ myIcon.name }}</v-icon>
                  </v-btn>
                </template>
                <span>Steady</span>
              </v-tooltip>
            </template>

            <v-list>
              <v-list-item>
                <v-icon
                  x-large
                  :color="colors.green"
                  @click="changeSupplierStatusToUp()"
                >mdi-chevron-up</v-icon>
              </v-list-item>
              <v-divider></v-divider>
              <v-list-item>
                <v-icon 
                 x-large
                :color="colors.grey"
                @click="changeSupplierStatusToMid()"
              >mdi-unfold-less-vertical</v-icon>
              </v-list-item>
                <v-divider></v-divider>
              <v-list-item>
                <v-icon
                  x-large
                  :color="colors.red"
                  @click="changeSupplierStatusToDown()"
                >mdi-chevron-down</v-icon>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
        </v-menu>
      </v-toolbar>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```